# Get IActiveScript of current page in IE

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, com, bho, iactivescript

I have an IE plugin (BHO) and I want to access script engine.

I want to start profiling it, so `IActiveScript` interface pointer is probably needed.

I have `IWebBrowser2` pointer, from that I tried getting `IHTMLDocument` (`get_Document`) and querying it to `IActiveScript` and `IActiveScriptSite` with no success.

I also tried `IHTMLDocument->get_Script`, but that returns just script `IDispatch` pointer (same as `IActiveScript::GetScriptDispatch`).

Comment: Why do you need to access the engine itself?

Comment: I want to attach profiler IActiveScriptProfilerCallback to it. I am working on JavaScript deobfuscator and using profiler I want to hook function and script creation (FunctionCompiled and ScriptCompiled).